# How can I pass a custom comparator function while object creation and how do I use it in the custom parent class in C++?

Tags: c++, tree, comparator

I'm creating a Tree class for generic data .

```cpp
class AVL{

    node<T>* root;

public :

    AVL(/*comparator function for custom objects*/){
        //at the time of object creation , the function should be passed and I have to get it
    }

    void insert(T data){
        //while inserting I can compare with the root and decide if it goes to left or right of bst
    }

};
    //in main class

    bool comparator(T data1, T data2){
        //compare logic
    }
```

How shall I pass the function present in the main class to the tree class , and how do I accept it at the custom class ?

Comment: Does the comparator have to be a class member? Normally they are free functions.  If it has to stay a member, consider wrapping the function with a lambda expression so you can more easily capture the instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

In both C and C++, you can pass a function pointer:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions

```cpp
template <typename T>
class AVL {
public:
    AVL(int (*comparer)(T left, T right)) 
      : comparer(comparer)    // store via member initialization list
    { }
    void insert(T data) {     // the method
        if (comparer(data, 4)) { /* ... */ }
    }

private:
    int (*comparer)(T left, T right); // the function pointer member
};

AVL<int> a { [](int left, int right) { return left < right; } };
```

In modern C++ you can store it in a `std::function<void(T)>`, which is a broader type that can store more flexible lambdas that reference or capture outside variables:

```cpp
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
class AVL {
public:
    template<typename F>
    AVL(F comparer) 
      : comparer(comparer) // store via member initialization list
    { }
    void insert(T data) {
        if (comparer(data, 4)) { /* ... */ }
    }
private:
    std::function<bool(T, T)> comparer; // the function pointer member
};

/* ... */
int anotherVariable;
AVL<int> a { [anotherVariable](int left, int right) { return left < right + anotherVariable; } };
```